# how to add and sort multidimentional array in python?

Tags: python, sorting

My code is something like below

```
for i in re.finditer('someinteger(.+?)withanother(.+?)', html):
    x = i.group(1)
    y = i.group(2)
```

Here x and y related to each other. If I want to index them in an array or something and sort the index based on x how do i approach. Considering index length is only 4 or 5. Meaning (i) will loop for max 4-5 times.

A quick code would be help. No clue with multi arrays.

Comment: Are you parsing HTML with regex...

Comment: Obligatory SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: considering regex html is not going to be an issue...

Comment: @Esenti: That link is getting really old, provides incorrect and unhelpful information and has nothing to do with this question. Could people please stop this knee-jerk reaction every time someone mentions "HTML" and "regex" in a post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first retrieve the values into a list. `re.findall()` will do that automatically:

```
values = re.findall(r'someinteger(.+?)withanother(.+?)', html)
```

Then you can sort the list:

```
values.sort()
```

if you want to sort by `x` (in your example).

For example:

```
>>> s = "someinteger5withanother1someinteger4withanother2someinteger3withanother3"
>>> values = re.findall(r'someinteger(.+?)withanother(.+?)', s)
>>> values
[('5', '1'), ('4', '2'), ('3', '3')]
>>> values.sort()
>>> values
[('3', '3'), ('4', '2'), ('5', '1')]
```

Of course you're still dealing with strings, if you want to sort numerically, you either need to do

```
values = [(int(x), int(y)) for x,y in values]
```

to convert them all to integers, or do

```
values.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Comment: I understood up to the sorting part..but how do i retrieve all or any individual pair?

Comment: `values` contains all the values, and `values[n]` contains the `n`th pair (counting from 0).